# Naka-rushton function

Tags: functions

I am trying to figure out how to transform the naka-rushton equation to a S-shaped function.
The naka-rushton equations is defined by
\begin{equation}
R(C) = R_{max}\frac{C^n}{C^n+K^n}+b,
\end{equation}
where $R$ is the response to contrast $C$, $K$ is the asymptotic  maximum response amplitude, $K$ is the semisaturation constant and $n$ is proportional to the slope of the curve at the point where the contrast is taken to be $K$.

The S-shaped function I would like to transform is to a sigmoidal function as:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\beta(x-x_0))},
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\ln(C)$. Then

$$\frac{1}{1+\exp(\beta(x-x_0))}=\frac{1}{1+\frac1{C_0^\beta}C^\beta}.$$

On the other hand,
$$R_{max}\frac{C^n}{C^n+K^n}+b=R_{max}-R_{max}\frac1{1+\frac1{K^n}C^n}+b=\frac A{1+\frac1{K^n}C^n}+B.$$